# Formatting an array element

Tags: java, arrays, date, generics, format

Here's the scenario. User enters 3 types of inputs:

```
1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM_5/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM_
_5/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

The input is for date range query.

1st input: Split by the _ delimiter: Broken into Start date and end date.

2nd input: Split by the _ delimiter: Input is only the start date.

3rd input: Split by the _ delimiter: Input is only the end date.

Input is retrieved by generic return type

```
String dbFormat = AppConstant.DB_DATE_FORMAT;
String format = AppConstant.DATE_FORMAT;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dates[] = searchValue.split("_", -1);
String start = "".equals(dates[0]) ? df.format(new Date(0L)) : dates[0];
String end = "".equals(dates[1]) ? df.format(new Date()) : dates[1];
filters.add(String.format("%s between to_date('%s', '%s') and to_date('%s', '%s')", columnKey, start, dbFormat, end, dbFormat));
```

The part that I need help on is,the date for the variable start and end should be in UTC format.As you guys can see, I've managed to convert new `Date(0L)` and `new Date()` to UTC format.
But I cant seem to format `dates[0]` and `dates[1]` to UTC.

Any ideas how to convert `dates[0]` and `dates[1]` into UTC time format? Can it be done in the same line.

I tried `df.format(dates[0])` but its not working.

I'm sorry if I may sound like a nood, but I'm new to java and I'm learning each day.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse those string input dates as a different format using the `parse` function on a new `SimpleDateFormat` (using format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a`) and that will give you a `Date` to then pass into `format` for the `SimpleDateFormat` you already have.

```
String dbFormat = AppConstant.DB_DATE_FORMAT;
String format = AppConstant.DATE_FORMAT;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dates[] = searchValue.split("_", -1);
String start = "".equals(dates[0]) ? df.format(new Date(0L)) : df.format(df2.parse(dates[0]));
String end = "".equals(dates[1]) ? df.format(new Date()) : df.format(df2.parse(dates[1]));
filters.add(String.format("%s between to_date('%s', '%s') and to_date('%s', '%s')", columnKey, start, dbFormat, end, dbFormat))
```